# Proving a map that admits local sections is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: X \to Y$ be continuous such there exists an open cover of $Y$, i.e.,
$$
\bigcup_{j \in J} V_j = Y
$$
where for each $V_j$ there is a continuous map $g_j: V_j \to X$, and for all $y \in V_j$ we have
$
f(g_j(y)) = y.
$ We are to show this a quotient map.

The surjective condition is easy, i.e., if $y \in Y$ then there exists $V_j \ni y$ such that
$
g_j(y) \in X
$ and $f(g_j(y)) = y$.

Showing that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ implies $U$ is open in $Y$ is giving me much more trouble. So far, I have if $W := f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, then for each $j \in J$ that $g^{-1}_j(W)$ is open in $Y$ since $V_j$ is open in $Y$. I'm not sure if this is false start, but this is what I have so far.

Comment: It's a great start. Now all you have to do is show that $U$ is the union of the open sets $g_j^{-1}(W)$.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex Kruckman said in his comment, it suffices to show that $\bigcup_j g_j^{-1}(W) = U$ (since all $g_j^{-1}(W)$ are open in $Y$).

We have
$$y \in \bigcup_j g_j^{-1}(W) \Leftrightarrow \exists j  : y \in g_j^{-1}(W) \Leftrightarrow \exists j  : y \in V_j \wedge  g_j(y) \in W = f^{-1}(U) \\ \Leftrightarrow \exists j  :  y \in V_j \wedge f(g_j(y)) \in U \Leftrightarrow \exists j  :  y \in V_j \wedge y \in U \Leftrightarrow y \in U .$$